# no_file_data error when upload file name contains japanese to slack using slack upload api

Tags: python, lambda, slack-api

I'm trying to upload a file with name contains Japanese charaters to slack like: `/tmp/結果.xlsx`
The request response with `no_file_data` error and no file is sended to slack.
But when I change file name to `/tmp/result.xlsx`, every thing is fine.
I have no idea that what went wrong.

`job.py`

```
from botocore.vendored import requests
import urllib.request


def execute():
    params = {'token': 'my-slack-token',
              'channels': 'test-channel', 'initial_comment': 'test-comment'}

    file_name = "/tmp/結果.xlsx"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(
        'http://download-url', file_name)
    file = {'file': open(file_name, 'rb')}
    res = requests.post(url="https://slack.com/api/files.upload", params=params, files=file)
    print(res.text)
```

and `main.py`

```
import job


def execute(event, context):
    job.execute()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': "Done!"
    }
```

When this lambda is triggered I got a result `<Response [200]> {"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"}` but if I change file name to `result.xlsx`, every thing will be fine

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Code be a UTF8 encoding problem Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7